# Javascript new date date conversion

Tags: javascript, date

I have a mysql table with dates in it (format: yyy-mm-dd). I then retrieve the dates and save them, however in the procures I change the dates format to make the user viewing easier for the task at hand. My issue is that when I get dates that are too far in the future (out a few months) they change and fall a day behind (otherwise it works fine). I spent a lot of time reading up on how the javascript date conversion works but I still do not have a firm understanding. Without what i wrote the date always comes in after the conversion a day behind. Also I am located in ohio. Here is what I have:

```
    var x = offset*60000;  
    var time = new Date (item.start);
    var time2=time.getTime();
    var time3=time2+x;
    var start = $.datepicker.formatDate('D, d M, yy', new Date (time3));
```

what is the issue here? Also if you could give a quick explanation for my education, that would be great. Thanks.

Comment: What is the format of `item.start`? And what is `x`?

Comment: Oh i am so sorry it is mysql date format of yyyy-mm-dd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the format you are passing to the `Date` constructor <strike>does not seem valid according to - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date</strike> (i.e. a version of the ISO8601 extended format) is a valid [ES5 format](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15) but is not correctly parsed by the browser.

So something like this should be what you need:

http://jsfiddle.net/xfz6L/

```
var date_string = "2012-11-02";

var first_try = new Date(date_string);
alert(first_try.toDateString());

// The following is the code you would use
var date_split = date_string.split("-");
var second_try = new Date(date_split[0], +date_split[1]-1, date_split[2]);
alert(second_try.toDateString());
```

Since <strike>the problem seems to be that it is not a valid format</strike> not all browsers correctly parse the ISO8601 format, my solution is to use the string provided and manipulate it to work as a valid constructor.

The easiest way I can think of is passing the "year", "month", and "day" in that order to the constructor.

To do that, you need to split the string by `-` and then pass each array index to the constructor.

The reason I subtract "1" from the month is that the range is from 0 to 11.

Comment: great answer and thanks so much for the explanation, I did not know the date was not in the valid format!

Comment: When converting a string to a date ojbect, **always** manually parse the string, do not leave it up to the Date constructor or `Date.parse`. In theory, ISO8601 format should work but it doesn't work reliably for all browsers in use. Also, the appropriate reference is [ECMA-262](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15), not the documentation for a particular browser. Oh, and `+date_split[1]-1` can be just `date_split[1]-1` or `--date_split[1]`.

Comment: @Mr.SirKingOsman—your date **is** in a valid format (if by "valid" you mean consistent with the [appropriate standard](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15)). Unfortunately, browsers are not sufficiently compliant to reliably parse it.

Comment: oh, i completely understand, i meant not valid for javascript date but i now see what you mean. And thanks for the clarifications!

Comment: btw @RobG while you are here any suggestions on comma delineating the date? I cant seem to find documentation on `.toDateString()` that suggests i can have it do that. ex of desired outcome `Wed, 17 Oct, 2012`

Comment: @RobG When I refer to "not valid" in this context, all I meant was not valid for `Date` object constructor - because it wasn't something that was being parsed correctly (for whatever reason). Although as I re-read the `Date.parse` page (because it says the `Date` constructor can parse any format that `Date.parse` does), it does say `For example, "2011-10-10" (just date) or "2011-10-10T14:48:00 (date and time) can be passed and parsed.` But even using `Date.parse` doesn't parse it correctly - http://jsfiddle.net/kckUt/ . Why don't browsers parse it correctly?

Comment: @RobG Good point about the second argument using `+` - after I wrote it, I realized the `- 1` will automatically convert the first value to a number first, but kept it anyways. And I don't know why but I hadn't thought of using `--`, good idea!

Comment: @ianpgall—your guess is a good as anyone's on that. I'd suggest that browser developers were (are?) very US–centric and don't understand that most of the world doesn't use month/day/year. But that's just my guess. And there is no method for formatting the output, other than [`toLocaleString`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.5) and variants, which are inconsistent (and Chrome ignores my local settings anyway). A significant short coming of ECMA-262 I think.

Comment: @RobG Hmm, interesting. I was expecting you to provide a link for reasoning, like it was very well known or something and I just didn't know about it. It's just weird - the ISO format is well known and is always year-month-day(optional time), isn't it? I mean, as I think it over more, I guess it makes sense that it would have trouble understand the difference between month-day-year and year-month-day, but I'd also think that the presence of 4 digits in the beginning would trigger ISO format. Anyways, I guess the lesson is that using milliseconds from epoch is the best way?

Comment: @ianpgall—I'd already referenced the [appropriate section in ES5](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15), however not all browsers in use support ISO dates yet. There is also [toISOString](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.43), but I think you are correct that ms since epoch UTC is the most transportable and convenient. There's some good information on dates at [J R Stockton's site](http://www.merlyn.demon.co.uk/js-dates.htm) if you can tolerate his punctilious style (many can't, but the information is good so worth persevering).

Comment: @RobG Right, I just thought there'd be some big controversy about browsers not supporting this stuff (maybe there is we haven't seen), but I guess that's simple enough - not all browser support ISO. Hey, anything suggested is a good enough reason to attempt to read it :)

Answer (score 0):

Note that `yyyy-mm-dd` format is a valid [ISO date](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) but unfortunately the JavaScript [`Date` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) only supports values of millseconds since the epoch, an [RFC 2822 date](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-14), or separate date components.

In this case, using the date components might be easiest:

```javascript
function parseDate(isoDateStr) {
  var parts = isoDateStr.split(/-/);
  return new Date(parts[0], parts[1]-1, parts[2]);
}
```

Note that the month value is zero-based instead of one-based.

Comment: You should reference [the appropriate standard](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.3.1), not on a community wikki that documents the behaviour of a particular browser (unless you are developing solely for that browser and trust the wikki).